# nuget package urls - how to find source

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm attempting to use nuget on a corporate network. Our security software is blocking the majority of the nuget packages (gives 403 errors).

I'm trying to find out what URL's need to be unblocked to get nuget fully working, but other than our security team scanning our logs to see what I've accessed I'm unable to find out where the packages are actually being hosted.

I can't see anything on nuget.org that helps. Does anyone have any ideas, am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Haha :D small world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the repo is located at https://nuget.org/api/v2/
If that url isn't enough, Fiddler should be of some help.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I ended up using Fiddler on a PC with no network filtering to id the url's. You'd be amazed how many URL's it uses for the different packages. I got all of them unblocked and nuget now appears to be fully working. Cheers

Comment: Nuget is f*cked-up piece of software. It will pull a mess of packages for whatever repos you have enabled.