# How to view the URL of a Nuget Feed?

Tags: nuget

We just started having a problem with Nuget. We can get a list of packages, but when we try to install certain ones (like jQuery) we are getting a 403 (Forbidden) error. I believe that our proxy (McAfee) is blocking certain URLs.

It seems to be the same problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997827/error-when-trying-to-install-nuget-package). They solved it using Wireshark. I can't use Wireshark because (you guessed it) it's blocked here.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513175/nuget-package-urls-how-to-find-source) mentions going to https://nuget.org/api/v2/ but when I do that I only see about 8 lines of XML.

So my question is: how can I see the URL for a Nuget feed so that I can request that our network guys unblock it without using Wireshark or Fiddler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download Nuget Packages Without VS/NuGet Package Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482319/download-nuget-packages-without-vs-nuget-package-manager)

Answer (score 11):

Install the command-line nuget.exe client from https://nuget.org/nuget.exe

Then run `nuget sources` to view the registered endpoints. This will typically list something like this:

```
D:\>nuget sources
Registered Sources:

1.  https://nuget.org/api/v2/ [Enabled]
    https://nuget.org/api/v2/
```

From this you can see the base endpoints which are likely being used within Visual Studio or the PS tools.

You can also use an HTTP inspector like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to capture the exact calls from the nuget client (whether command-line or Visual Studio) to the nuget.org endpoint, resulting in something like this:

[image: Fiddler2 sniffing HTTPS traffic from nuget.exe to nuget.org]

In the 'Process' column you can see the calls originating from nuget.exe. To see the exact URLs you can configure Fiddler to intercept and decrypt HTTPS, or alternatively specify a non-HTTPS Source like this `nuget list log4net -Source http://nuget.org/api/v2/` which results in Fiddler being able to see the plain HTTP responses:

[image: Fiddler2 sniffing HTTP traffic from nuget.exe to nuget.org]

In this case, one of the calls from nuget.exe was:

```
GET http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&$orderby=Id&$skip=0&$top=30&searchTerm='log4net'&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=false HTTP/1.1
```

The nuget clients make several calls to retrieve even just a package list but AFAIK, the calls are all standard HTTP `GET`, `POST`, etc., not WebDAV calls, so there should be no reason why these calls should not work with a proxy as long as the nuget.org site itself is not blocked.